# How do I properly use reportValidity() when I want to show an error bubble for just one input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate and show an error bubble on just **one** of the tens of input fields I have on a given form.
Each input field has its own required and pattern attributes set, along a function that validates input on `onBlur`.

To do so, I call a function on `onBlur` that validates, sets a custom error message using `setCustomValidity()` and then calls `reportValidity()` on the form element to show the custom message on a bubble... that validates my first field alright, but when I onBlur that first field and it's valid, the next input field is showing an error bubble.

I know my problem is that `reportValidity()` validates the whole form and the empty required fields are indeed invalid... but how do I force it to show the error bubble on just the field I'm leaving? I'm having the hardest time figuring this out.

Just to be clear, this is what I refer when I say error bubble. I don't know it's technical name (And I would like to know it!)

[image: to]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `reportValidity()` on the [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Methods), you can call `reportValidity()` on each [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Methods).

The Example below shows two required `HTMLInputElement`'s, and the second one is validated.

```js
document.getElementById("2")
  .reportValidity();
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="1" required>
  <input id="2" required>
</form>
```